# Does this Monad instance follow the monadic laws?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am new to Haskell and I'm trying to figure out if the following snippets of code obey the Monad Laws.

```
newtype SubsM a = SubsM {runSubsM :: Context -> Either Error (a, Env)}

instance Functor SubsM where
  fmap f m = m >>= \a -> return (f a)

instance Applicative SubsM where
  pure = return; (<*>) = ap

instance Monad SubsM where
    return x = SubsM (\ctx -> Right (x, fst ctx))
    SubsM m >>= f = SubsM $ \c -> case m c of 
        Left(Error s) -> Left(Error s)
        Right (a, env) -> runSubsM (f a) (env, snd c)
    fail s = SubsM $ \c -> Left(Error s)
```

On the right side the monad contains the state, which in this case may contain an error message while on the left side it contains the context. I have been looking up the monadic laws which state that:
 - we need to get the left part of the monad (left identity)
 - we need to get the right part of the monad (right identity)
 - we need to be able to chain functions (associativity)

Comment: What are `Context`, `Error` and `Env` ? Please  write the modules you import.

Comment: You've stated the problem, but not any attempt to solve it. Substitute your definitions for `>>=` and `return` in the monad laws, go from there.